# How to access js files from components folder in React Native ios project

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, react-native

I am unable to access components folder in React Native Project IOS.

**I am getting following error:**

> Unable to resolve module ./Login from
>   ....../ReactNative/ReactNativeProject/components/App.js: Unable to find
>   this module in its module map or any of the node_modules directories
>   under ......./ReactNative/ReactNativeProject/components/Login.j and its
>   parent directories.

I have referred following link:
http://caroaguilar.com/post/react-native-navigation-tutorial/

**index.ios.js** (ReactNativeProject/index.ios.js)

```
"use strict";

import React, { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './components/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeProject', () => App);
```

**App.js** (ReactNativeProject/components/App.js)

```
  'use strict'

    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {
        AppRegistry,
        StyleSheet,
        NavigatorIOS,
    } from 'react-native';
    var Login = require('./Login');

    class App extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
              <NavigatorIOS
                style={styles.navigationContainer}
                initialRoute={{
                title: "Login Page",
                component: Login,
              }} />
          );
        }
    }

    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
        navigationContainer: {
            flex: 1
        }
    });

    export default App;
```

**Login.js** (ReactNativeProject/components/Login.js)

```
"use strict";
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {
        StyleSheet,
        Text,
        TextInput
    } from 'react-native';
    import Button from 'react-native-button';
    import styles from './login';


    class Login extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              username: "",
              password: "",

            };
        }

        render() {
            return (

              <View style={styles.container}>
                  <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                      <TextInput
                          style={styles.inputUsername}
                          placeholder="Enter email ID"
                          value={this.state.username}
                          clearButtonMode = 'while-editing'/>
                      <TextInput
                          style={styles.inputPassword}
                          placeholder="Enter Password"
                          value={this.state.password}
                          password={true}
                          secureTextEntry={true}
                          clearButtonMode = 'while-editing' />

                     <Button style={styles.login}
                             styleDisabled={{color: 'red'}}>
                             Login
                      </Button>
                  </View>
              </View>
            );
        }

    module.exports = Login;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried this so far and got the solution for this.

One mistake I did in **App.js**:

I have replaced `var Login = require('./Login');`

by

```
import Login from './Login';
```

The js files under components folder also changed as follows, except App.js

Changes in Login.js:

```
class Login extends Component {
   }
```

changed to

```
class Login extends React.Component {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well I did this way to import `js` files from **1 back root directory** and **root directory** of entire project structure.

I have following directory structure.

`App.js` file at `root directory`

`Splash.js` file at `MyApp -> Splash -> Splash.js`

`Home.js` file at `MyApp -> Home -> Home.js`

`TextViewComponent` file at `MyApp -> CustomComponents -> TextViewComponent.js`

**How I accessed all files across the all files.**

[image]

Hope this would help you too.

**Done.**